# Accessing netflix api from python's urllib2 results in 500 error

Tags: python, json, urllib2, netflix

I'm currently trying to fix a Kodi plugin called NetfliXBMC.

It uses this url to get information on specific movies:

```
http://www.netflix.com/JSON/BOB?movieid=<SOMEID>
```

While trying to build a minimal case to ask this question I discovered that it's not even necessary to be logged in to access the information, which simplifies my question a lot.

Querying information about a movie works from wget, from curl, from incognito chrome etc. It just never works from urllib2:

```
# wget works just fine
$: wget -q -O- http://www.netflix.com/JSON/BOB?movieid=80021955
    {"contextData":"{\"cookieDisclosure\":{\"data\":{\"showCookieBanner\":false}}}","result":"success","actionErrors":null,"fieldErrors":null,"actionMessages":null,"data":[output omitted for brevity]}

# so does curl
$: curl http://www.netflix.com/JSON/BOB?movieid=80021955
        {"contextData":"{\"cookieDisclosure\":{\"data\":{\"showCookieBanner\":false}}}","result":"success","actionErrors":null,"fieldErrors":null,"actionMessages":null,"data":[output omitted for brevity}


# but python's urllib always gets a 500
$: python -c "import urllib2; urllib2.urlopen('http://www.netflix.com/JSON/BOB?movieid=80021955').read()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

$: python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

What I've tried so far: several different user-agent strings, initializing a urlopener with a cookie jar, plain old urllib (doesn't raise an exception but receives the same error page).

I'm really curious as to why this might be. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Curious, it works fine with requests library

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser, it also works find with ancient `urllib`!-)  Makes you want to slap a tcp tracer on and see how exactly urllib2 is managing to tickle a netflix bug (500 == server-side bug) when any of the others don't.  But I'd just file a bug on whatever netflix uses as an issue tracker and let them debug **their** problem:-).

Comment: @alex the thing is it seems netflix is retiring it's API, I doubt they'd be willing to help with this. It didn't work with plain `urllib` for me

Comment: It doesn't work with manual http over `telnet` either :s. I'll do a few more tests with it and update the question with whatever I find out.

Comment: @gnp, I shd have specified "urllib with python 2.7" (no `urlopen` in `urllib` with Python 3.any).  Anyway, yep, if that API's deprecated they surely won't spend cycles debugging its buggy implementation -- tcp tracing to find out exactly what's happening in each case is the one way to go.

Comment: I sniffed the http session with firebug on firefox and started adding the same headers one by one on a telnet session, it is definitely related to a missing 'Accept:' header. As soon as I get my hands on a python shell I'll do a final test and report.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a bug on netflix' side when no `Accept` header is sent.

This doesn't work:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.open("http://www.netflix.com/JSON/BOB?movieid=80021955")
```

Adding a proper accept header makes it work:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
mimeAccept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
opener.addheaders = [('Accept', mimeAccept)]
opener.open("http://www.netflix.com/JSON/BOB?movieid=80021955")
[...]
```

Of course, there is another bug there: it returns a `500 internal server error` instead of a `400 bad request` when the problem was clearly on the request.